# Why I have to use vs2005 for InfoPath2010 programming

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

Hi 
Any reasones that I have to use vs2005 for InfoPath2010 programming.Is there a settings that I can let infopath to open VS2010 instead of VS2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Visual Studio Tools for Applications (part of the Office installs). No point in speculating why MS decided to go that way, although InfoPath was the only one of the products that didn't support VSTA. Agree with you that it is quite annoying!

Currently there is no setting to open IP projects in VS2010. You might be able to play around with the references and settings but it would be trial and error to get it working.